# What can I use to view media in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I sometimes like to be able to listen to mp3s and watch video files without saving them first.

I used to do this with the Quicktime plugin but I have that bug with 64-bit operating systems where the control bar is black (This hasn't been fixed to my knowledge).

Is there something else I can use?

Comment: ask someone else to download and play the media with the volume turned up really high.

Comment: Sorry Brian ... I don't see how you can play the media in *your computer* without downloading it into *your computer* first. It may be a matter of definition, though: a Quicktime plugin must have been downloading files for you to view them, *even if* the downloading took place in the background, and you weren't aware of it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to stream.

Answer (score 1):

Check these out:

[**Online Music Player (OMusic):**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4617)

> OMusic is a Firefox music extension
>   with which you can listen to mp3s
>   while browsing. It supports online and
>   local music playback, as well as
>   sharing music list with your friends.
>
> Unlike the others, OMusic is not a
>   modeless player. It has two modes:
>
> - A 'simple file' mode to test online    music links and listen to it before
>     putting it into your list
> - A 'play list' mode to enjoy your    collection of music and have fun.

**[VLCWatcha:](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14259)**

> This extension is a mighty practical
>   use of the famous media player VLC
>   (www.videolan.org) through the VLC
>   mozilla plugin. It allows to visualize
>   directly in our browser the content of
>   whatever media files before it
>   finishes downloading. You just have to
>   right click the link (it must be an
>   .avi, .flv, .mp3, etc.) you want to
>   watch and choose the mighty "View with
>   VLC" button.